# Print values in a listbox with for loop,but some of them to be displayed as strings

Tags: c#, winforms

I've just started with programming  using c# for creating windows form app in VB.The exercise is  the following : 
"Write a program that prints the numbers 1 to 100. 
But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for multiples of five print "Buzz". 
For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz"."
How can this be done using for loop or while/do-while loop?

```
 int sum = 0;
            string text = " ";

            for (int counter = 0; counter <=100; counter++)
            {
                sum += counter;
                text = text + " " + counter.ToString;
            }
            lsbAdd.Items.Add(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `winforms` tag is different from `windows`.

Comment: Have you heard about the modulus operator?

Comment: I have just googled for the exercise and I also understand the usage of % but I want the result to be shown  in  the control listbox  in .net framework,not in  console app

Comment: I have added an extra duplicate showing how to add items to a listbox.